# What are the possibilities of Using Redis with SQL Database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nosql, redis

Redis as Main Database and as Cache. and how to implement it ?

What are other pros and cons of using this type of architecture.

Answer (score 2):

I can say that redis is pretty fast, but I cannot pronounce myself for pros/cons.

For C# language bindings I can recommend [ServiceStack.Redis](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/redis-client/redis-client).

If you read the docs you'll immediately figure out how to implement "it".

Also see here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

Comment: @VijayantKatyal if this answer helped you or led you to the solution, please accept it using the check mark on the left and consider voting up using the up arrow. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The database you choose really depends on the problem you're trying to solve and the data needs of your solution.

Pros would be high scalability and the performance that goes with it.

Cons are increased pain in the assness and you lose some of the consistency guarantees that conventional sql/oracle provide.

If you need more info I can try to help out

Comment: Hey @AndrewWalters and thanks for your answer. I'm designing a program with a model that is going to evolve to a very complex inheritance hierarchy, and we have to leave it open to future expansion, meaning the model structure will constantly expand and change. I thought Redis would make a nice choice instead of SQL-Server relational. Is this a good choice? Any other things to consider? (I'm using ASP.NET Core with EF for the identity models and other basic stuff).